# jquery - multiple submit button in jsp and unable to retrieve the button value in validator class

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc application with jsp and jquery in the front end. I have multiple buttons on this jsp page and have to do different validations based on what gets clicked. I am stuck here almost for over 3 days trying to fix myself.

here is the jsp code 
    `<button id="previous" class="" type="reset">Previous</button> <br>'
<span id="saveSpan"><button id="save" name="save" type="submit">Save</button></span>`
    `<span id="submitSpan"><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button></span><br>`
    `<button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>`

**I need to differentiate the click on save vs submit to do different validations.** reading on the forums, I gave name to the save button as .val() would not work with out name.

**MyRequestVO.java** - is the form object that has all the values. Its equivalent in the jspclass is **myRequestVO**. I have defined an attribute **btnText** in this classand expecting to set its value through the following javascript/jQuery

The validator class is invoked before coming to the controller. I have been trying to get the string of submitted button text to call the right logic in the validator class. No matter, what I do, the value is returned as null.
`$('#save').click(function() {`

```
            if($('#userId').val() == ""){
                alert("Select UserId);
            }else{

                **var save = $( this ).text();
                $("#btnText").val("save");**
```

// The above 2 lines are the code that i am trying to add to get the value of save assigned to the formclass attribute. Here is where I am not getting it right. Please help me get the button value transferred to the java class.

```
                $('#myRequestVO').attr('action','$history');
                $('#myRequestVO').submit();
            }

            return false;
        });
```

In fact, I am trying to set a value as the validator class is triggered before. My idea is to somehow send a request param to the validator class based on the button click. In the validator, I do not have access to request object except for the value object.

On submit, the existing code is calling this and id need to pass a parameter from jsp page to set to myRequestVO to use in validator to do different validation for save and submit
ModelandView( @Valid myRequestVO, BindingResult result, HTtpRequest request, HttpResponse response)

Answer (score 0):

A code fix:

-Missing a quote in the alert for select user id
Also, you state that you call a btnText class(.), but then call for a btnText id(#)

```
<input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" value="" /> <br />
<button id="previous" class="" type="reset">Previous</button> <br />
<span id="saveSpan"><button id="save" name="save" type="submit">Save</button></span>  <br />
<span id="submitSpan"><button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button></span> <br />  <button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>

$('#save').click(function() {   
    if($('#userId').val() == ""){
        alert("Select UserId");
    }else{
        var save = $( this ).text();
        $(".btnText").val("save");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwolybug/4qhz0axv/

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo on the "select user id". How can I get the $btnText get assigned a value of "save". I am still getting nothing for btnText. I see that there is a dot in front of btnText. I have a list of text fields and when I click save they need to be validated and stay on the same page. If I click on submit, the control goes to the next page. I need to capture the click and do the required.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to set a value as the validator class is triggered before. My idea is to somehow send a request param to the validator class based on the button click. In the validator, I do not have access to request object except for the value object. 

On submit, the existing code is calling this and id need to pass a parameter from jsp page to set to myRequestVO to use in validator to do different validation for save and submit
ModelandView( @Valid myRequestVO, BindingResult result, HTtpRequest request, HttpResponse response)

Comment: First question, is the $btnText a class or an id? If it is a class, you would call it by $(".btnText") and an id would be $("#btnText). No preference as to which way you want to do it, both should work. To set the value, it should work with $("#btnText).val("save"). 

Clicking on the button takes you to the next page since that is the default click option. You would have to remove the default and change the click to something else, or get rid of the type="submit", change to just a button and then the above code should work.

Comment: Look at jquery submit link below. It has information about changing the default event for submits. You can then redirect the submit to validate the code before submitting and staying on the same page. 
http://api.jquery.com/submit/